# Finding the distinct record from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the records from 2 tables 
procedure and procedure_user_map, i am writing a query in sql sever
in order to get the records based on the limit and offset which is selected
from ui, i am writing the following query in order to get the records

but i am not getting 10 records the rownum() function is not working
after finding distinct instead it is putting count on the each row

```
WITH MD_Results AS 
(
    SELECT P.pk, P.procedure_name,
     RowNum() OVER (order by P.procedure_name asc) AS RowNum 
    FROM "procedure" P, "procedure_user_map" PUM 
    where P.pk = PUM.procedure_fk 
) 
SELECT DISTINCT "pk", "procedure_name", RowNum FROM MD_Results 
WHERE RowNum > 0 AND RowNum <= 0 + 10
```

I want to get the distinct records of procedure and do a rownum() over that
to get the count correct

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
WITH MD_Results AS 
(
    SELECT P.pk, P.procedure_name,
     RowNum() OVER (PARTITION BY P.procedure_name order by P.procedure_name asc) AS RowNum 
    FROM "procedure" P, "procedure_user_map" PUM 
    where P.pk = PUM.procedure_fk 
) 
SELECT top 10 pk, procedure_name, RowNum FROM MD_Results 
WHERE RowNum > 1
```